# script/plugin says command not found when the file exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to upgrade rails 2.x to rails 3.0.0.

I am following this guide (http://www.rails-upgrade-checklist.com/#3.0) and it says to download this rails upgrade tool:

script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git

When I try that I get an error:

```
$ script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git
-bash: script/plugin: Permission denied
$ sudo script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git
Password:
sudo: script/plugin: command not found


$ ls script/
about   dbconsole destroy   performance process   server    spec_server
console   delayed_job generate  plugin    runner    spec    spin
$
```

How do I get this to work, I'm stuck on such an early step :)

Comment: try adding execute permisison to plugin. `chmod +x file`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra I did that and no change.